# Why do my Access linked subforms not display correctly when refreshed?

Tags: ms-access, forms, ms-access-2003, subforms

I have a form (Quote) with an auto-number ID, on the form at the moment are two subforms that show different items (sub 1 shows partition modules sub 2 shows partition abutments) both forms use the same parts tables to build them.

Both forms are linked to the quote form using the ID.

All works well until the forms is refreshed or re-loaded, subform 1 shows the module names and quantities and blank spaces for the abutment names but shows the quantiews for the abutments, the reverse of this is shown in the abutments subform 2.

When the lists for the variuos types and the detailed parts lists are printed they are correct.

This seems to be only a visual problem.

All based on Access 2003.

**Subform 1**

```
SELECT Quote_Modules.ModuleID, 
       Quote_Modules.QuoteID, 
       Quote_Modules.ModuleDescription, 
       Quote_Modules.ModuleQty, 
       Quote.Style, 
       Quote.Trim 
FROM Quote 
    INNER JOIN Quote_Modules ON Quote.QuoteID=Quote_Modules.QuoteID 
ORDER BY Quote_Modules.ModuleID;
```

**Subform 2**

```
SELECT Quote_Modules.ModuleID, 
       Quote_Modules.QuoteID, 
       Quote_Modules.ModuleDescription, 
       Quote_Modules.ModuleQty, 
       Quote.Style, 
       Quote.Trim 
FROM Quote 
    INNER JOIN Quote_Modules ON Quote.QuoteID=Quote_Modules.QuoteID 
ORDER BY Quote_Modules.ModuleID;
```

Comment: We need more to go on. Can you show some code?

Comment: I do not think that code is involved, but the SQL for the two subforms might be useful.

Comment: At the moment there is no code or SQL attached to either the form to the subforms, only the form ID links the subforms to the form

Comment: Look at the Record Source for the subforms. You will find it on the property sheet in design view. If it is an SQL string, post that, if it is the name of a query, post the SQL from the query, please.

Comment: Remou.

The SQL is from the query

Subform 1
SELECT Quote_Modules.ModuleID, Quote_Modules.QuoteID, Quote_Modules.ModuleDescription, Quote_Modules.ModuleQty, Quote.Style, Quote.Trim FROM Quote INNER JOIN Quote_Modules ON Quote.QuoteID=Quote_Modules.QuoteID ORDER BY Quote_Modules.ModuleID; 

Subform 2
SELECT Quote_Modules.ModuleID, Quote_Modules.QuoteID, Quote_Modules.ModuleDescription, Quote_Modules.ModuleQty, Quote.Style, Quote.Trim FROM Quote INNER JOIN Quote_Modules ON Quote.QuoteID=Quote_Modules.QuoteID ORDER BY Quote_Modules.ModuleID;

Comment: Which columns (by name) are not showing, please?

Comment: Uh, is it correct that the two subforms have the same Recordsource?

Comment: Remou.
Items not showing on both forms are QuoteID, Quote.Style, Quote.Trim and ModuleID.

If I could have your email address I will forward the complete database.

Comment: @Shaun I do not post my email address, however, if you visit http://forum.lessthandot.com/viewforum.php?f=95, you can attach a zip of the database to your post. You will also find that you can send private messages.

Comment: I suggest you make a new title for this post.  "New to programming" is not even a bit helpful!

Comment: If the two SQL statements for the subforms are (intentionally?) identical, why do you expect those subforms to show different information?